# Programmatically Dismiss the Chrome Extension Post-Install Message?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

On OS X, after installing a new chrome extension from the webstore, a default message in the form of a bubble (or infowindow, or tooltip) is displayed in the upper-right corner of the browser window.  This message is persistent until the mouse is clicked.

This is a problem, because I want to display my own custom message via chrome.notifications upon install, but will overlap with the default message because it's also being displayed in the upper-right for OS X.

So, is there a way to programmatically dismiss the default post-install message?  I tried several ways to dispatch events (click, mousedown, etc), but not having any luck because the chrome dev tool can not inspect the area of the toolbar/address bar from which the default message is being displayed.  Thus, I don't know what to target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't dismiss it with extension APIs.

It's partially a security measure - the user is informed that the thing that just got installed can be accessed and disabled from that UI location.

Comment: Maybe display your message on first popup click

Comment: Is this the right answer?  I would like to accept it but not sure.

Comment: I do not have a rigorous mathematical proof of it, if that's what you're asking. But I am sure of it.

Comment: Not asking for a mathematical proof.  :)  But was hoping for some link or info that would support your answer.  Then I would be happy to accept your answer.  Thanks.

Comment: Speaking of mathematical proofs. A positive proof is easy and constructive: "Here's an API that does this". A negative proof is hard: "[Here's a list of all available APIs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index), and none of them do that. You're welcome to check." There is no exhaustive list of "things API does not do" I can point you to.

Comment: Thanks, I will accept your answer because it is the most helpful.

Comment: @Xan is correct. One workaround is that you instantly open a new tab and show your info there. User gets diverted to this new tab and does not see default message. Evernote Clipper does that if you are looking for an example.